# Passing an array into Ruby Excel Document Generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to pass in an array to my Excel file Generator, however I recieve errors such as:

```
RuntimeError: Not an array ref in call to write_row()
```

when I attempt to run my script, can anyone tell me how best to pass in data to the following code?

module Accounting
module Datev
module Utils
class ExcelGenerator

```
    require 'writeexcel'

    # this class generates excel document and saves it with new path
    # Example:
    # d = [
    #   { name: 'Dima', dob: '27/02', city: 'Berlin' },
    #   { name: 'Conor', dob: '23/04', city: 'Berlin' },
    # ]
    # Accounting::Datev::Utils::ExcelGenerator.new(data: d, path: '~/text.xlsx').call
    # will create excel file text.xlsx in the home directory with the following content
    #  | name  | dob   | city   |
    #  | Dima  | 27/02 | Berlin |
    #  | Conor | 23/04 | Berlin |
    #

    attr_reader :data, :path, :workbook, :worksheet

    @array = [
       { name: 'Dima', dob: '27/02', city: 'Berlin' },
       { name: 'Conor', dob: '23/04', city: 'Berlin' }, ]

    def initialize(data:, path:)
      @data = data
      @path = path
    end

    def call
      # TODO: implement me``
      create_new_workbook
      add_worksheet
      write_new_worksheet
      save_file
    end

    def create_new_workbook
      @workbook  = WriteExcel.new('a_simple.xls')
    end

    def add_worksheet
      @worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet
    end

    def write_new_worksheet
      worksheet.write_row('A1', '#{array}')
    end

    def save_file
      workbook.close
    end
  end
end
```

end
end

Comment: syntax error, use "@" for instance variable: @worksheet.write_row('A1', '#{array}')

Comment: @Fernand I still receive that error unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't need to try convert array to string. But you should use different array format and use `write_col` method:

```rb
def initialize(data:, path:)
  @data = data
  @path = path
  @array = [
    ['name', 'dob', 'city'],
    ['Dima', '27/02', 'Berlin'], 
    ['Conor', '23/04','Berlin']
  ]
end

...

def write_new_worksheet
  worksheet.write_col('A1', @array)
end
```

You can found more information here http://writeexcel.web.fc2.com/en/doc_en.html#write_col

Comment: I still receive that error "RuntimeError: Not an array ref in call to write_row()
from /Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/writeexcel-1.0.5/lib/writeexcel/worksheet.rb:3216:in `write_col'

Comment: My bad. You initialize `@array` as a class variable instead of an instance variable so it doesn't available inside the `write_new_worksheet` method. Put @array initialization inside initialize method or make it constant. Will edit answer